# Why does OpenLDAP think my code didn't bind to the server?

Tags: c++, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to use the OpenLDAP C APIs to execute a search query against an AD.

```
#include <ldap.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    LDAP *ldp;
    auto ldap_version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    auto tls_cert_strat = LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER; //Never require identity cert from peer

    int err = ldap_initialize(&ldp,"ldap://1.1.1.1");
    if (err != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "unable to connect" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "connected, err == " << ldap_err2string(err) << "\n";

    ldap_set_option(ldp, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &ldap_version); //Set version to LDAPv3
    ldap_set_option(ldp, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, &tls_cert_strat);

    err = ldap_start_tls_s(ldp, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (err != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        char* msg;
        ldap_get_option(ldp, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, &msg);
        std::cerr << "unable to upgrade to TLS! err: " << ldap_err2string(err) << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "diagnostic msg: " << msg << "\n";
        ldap_memfree(msg);
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "start_tls request sent successfully, err == " << ldap_err2string(err) << "\n";

    err = ldap_tls_inplace(ldp);
    if (err != 1)
    {
        char* msg;
        ldap_get_option(ldp, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, &msg);
        std::cerr << "TLS handlers not installed! err: " << ldap_err2string(err) << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "diagnostic msg: " << msg << "\n";
        ldap_memfree(msg);
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "TLS handlers have been installed sucessfully" << "\n";

    //err = ldap_bind_s(ldp, "user@domain.com", "foo", LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE);
    err = ldap_simple_bind_s(ldp, "user@domain.com", "foo");
    if (err != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        char* msg;
        ldap_get_option(ldp, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, &msg);
        std::cerr << "Unable to bind to domain! err: " << ldap_err2string(err) << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "diagnostic msg: " << msg << "\n";
        ldap_memfree(msg);
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully bound to DC\n";

    char* base_dn = const_cast<char*>("dc=domain,dc=com");
    char* filters = const_cast<char*>("userPrincipalName=user");
    char* attr[4];

    attr[0] = const_cast<char*>("samaccountname");
    attr[1] = const_cast<char*>("cn");
    attr[2] = const_cast<char*>("mail");
    attr[3] = nullptr;

    LDAPMessage* ldp_msg;

    std::cout << "Executing LDAP search query\n";

    err = ldap_search_ext_s(ldp, base_dn, LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, filters, attr, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0, &ldp_msg);
    if (err != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        char* msg;
        ldap_get_option(ldp, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, &msg);
        std::cerr << "Unable to search domain! err: " << ldap_err2string(err) << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "diagnostic msg: " << msg << "\n";
        ldap_memfree(msg);
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Search executed successfully\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I build the code as follows:

```
g++8 -D LDAP_DEPRECATED -g -std=c++17 my_ldap.cpp -o my_ldap -l ldap
```

But when I execute it, I get the following error:

```
connected, err == Success
start_tls request sent successfully, err == Success
TLS handlers have been installed sucessfully
Successfully bound to DC
Executing LDAP search query
Unable to search domain! err: Operations error
diagnostic msg: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907E1, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580
```

This is where I'm confused: The diagnostic message says that I didn't bind, but given that `ldap_simple_search_s` returned LDAP_SUCCESS, that would mean that I did have a successful `bind`.

I would understand if the search fails with a message citing lack of authorization, filter not matching, etc.

The only other thing that I could think of is that I may have bound to one DN and executed a search against a different DN, but I checked for any typos several times, and nothing popped up.

Just FYI, `ldap_bind_s(ldp, "user@domain.com", "foo", LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE)` has the same behavior.
Now, if the DC didn't like my bind/authentication method, I would imagine that would've caused an error during the `bind` call, but nothing of the sort happened.

I thought about using the built-in debugging of the library as documented in the man pages for `ldap_set_option`, i.e. the `LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL` option, but the code doesn't compile when I try to use one of the options as shown in the man page (incidentally none of those options are defined in `ldap.h`)

What other angle should I be looking at to understand/resolve this problem?

Comment: the posted code is `C++` not `c`,  Please remove the `c` tag

Comment: @user3629249 Done. Although, my idea behind tagging it with C was to clarify that the OpenLDAP C APIs are being used and not some wrapper around it, e.g python-ldap.